# Is it possible to query Parquet files from SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, parquet

Is it possible to use SQLite for querying over Parquet files?

```
CREATE TABLE test USING parquet('test.parquet');

SELECT * from test;
```

Answer (score 4):

If your requirement is to query both SQLite data and Parquet data using lightweight and embeddable tool, you can also consider [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org) with [SQLite scanner extension](https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/sqlite_scanner).

Comment: Do you Python libs?

Comment: DuckDB has a Python API (https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview). SQLite scanner extension requires building it from C source though.

Comment: Except that SqlLite can deal with large (300M+) amounts of data while DuckDB may struggle enormously with this.

Comment: Reference re: DuckDB memory struggles: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26442745

Answer (score 4):

Use Pandas to import the data first!

```
import pandas as pd 
import sqlite3

parquet_path = 'my-data.parquet'
table_name = 'my_data_table'
query = f"SELECT * from {table_name}"

db_conn = sqlite3.connect(database='/tmp/my.db')

df_parquet = pd.read_parquet(parquet_path)
num_rows_inserted = df_parquet.to_sql(table_name, db_conn, index=False)

cursor = db_conn.execute(query)
```